# Debian 10 Persistent Naming Scheme Does Not Persist

Tags: debian, network-interface

I have minimal no-graphics Debian 10 with a single built-in ethernet interface and built-in wi-fi that I do not use. I do not have anything in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` . All I want to is to have interfaces to come up without logging in. I have these lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

The problem: sometimes the interface is named enp2s0 and sometimes enp3s0 so I added the same config for enp3s0.

It still does not work half of the times if enp3s0 comes up it managed to get different ip address from dhcp (for the same mac????? -- I have static address on dhcp server).

I noticed that it works if there `Failed to start Raise network interfaces` error.

The only abnormality during startup:

```
usb 2-10: Direct firmware load for ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu failed with error -2
```

There is nothing on this box beyond disk and network. Maybe I should disable bluetooth?

Please, help.

Comment: Are you sure that you get different IP addresses, and the it is the same MAC, and that these addresses are from DHCP? If so then there is something else going on.

Comment: This was an unrelated problem with my dhcp server,  I had fixed it in the mean time.

Comment: It is best to not list all of your unrelated problems. Can you edit the question to remove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following lines from `/etc/network/interfaces` (keep only `lo`):

```
auto enp2s0 
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

Create `10-persistent-net.link` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/10-persistent-net.link
```

with the following line:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=mac_address_here

[Link]
Name=enp2s0
```

Reboot your system.

See examples on [`man systemd.link`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/udev/systemd.link.5.en.html) and [CUSTOM SCHEMES USING .LINK FILES](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames#CUSTOM_SCHEMES_USING_.LINK_FILES)

[5.3. The modern network configuration without GUI](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_modern_network_configuration_without_gui)

Ubuntu: [Netplan configuration examples.](https://netplan.io/examples)

Comment: It worked, thank you. I am wondering is there a systematic description of ALL possible approaches to network configuration on recent Debian and Ubuntu?